# calling functions inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using google maps and i have working code to display markers on a map.  I now want to put this code inside of a function `view_maps()` and activate this function on click.  So far i get the errors **Maximum call stack size exceeded** and **getAddress is not a function**.  This works but when the code inside of `view_maps()` function i get these errors.

```
function view_maps() {
    function marker_map() {

        var url = "http://example.co.uk/deliveries/map/get_region_orders";
        var region = $("ul#regions").children("li[data-active='1']").attr("class");

        var data = {
            region: region
        };

        var obj = {};
        var locations = [];
        var details_array = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://example.co.uk/deliveries/map/get_region_orders",
            data: data,
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {

                var result = $.parseJSON(response);

                jQuery.each(result, function(i) {

                    var order_id = result[i].order_id;
                    var customer_name = result[i].customer_name;
                    var address_1 = result[i].address_1;
                    var address_2 = result[i].address_2;
                    var post_code = result[i].post_code;
                    var address = post_code;

                    var details = "<b>Order Number: " + order_id + "</b><br>" + address_1 + "<br>" + address_2 + "<br>" + post_code;

                    details_array.push(details);
                    locations.push(address);
                });

            }
        });

        obj['address'] = locations;
        obj['details'] = details_array;


        return (obj);

    }

    // delay between geocode requests - at the time of writing, 100 miliseconds seems to work well
    var delay = 70;

    // ====== Create map objects ======
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.381021, -2.608138);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("marker-map"), mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // ====== Geocoding ======
    function getAddress(search, count, next) {
        geo.geocode({
            address: search
        }, function(results, status) {
            // If that was successful
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                // Lets assume that the first marker is the one we want
                var p = results[0].geometry.location;
                var lat = p.lat();
                var lng = p.lng();
                // Output the data
                var msg = 'address="' + search + '" lat=' + lat + ' lng=' + lng + '(delay=' + delay + 'ms)<br>';
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += msg;
                // Create a marker
                createMarker(search, count, lat, lng);
            }
            // ====== Decode the error status ======
            else {
                // === if we were sending the requests to fast, try this one again and increase the delay
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    nextAddress--;
                    delay++;
                } else {
                    var reason = "Code " + status;
                    var msg = 'address="' + search + '" error=' + reason + '(delay=' + delay + 'ms)<br>';
                    //document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += msg;
                }
            }
            next();
        });
    }

    // ======= Function to create a marker
    function createMarker(add, count, lat, lng) {
        var contentString = add;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map: map,
            zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(details_array[count]);
            //infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        bounds.extend(marker.position);

    }

    // ======= An array of locations that we want to Geocode ========
    //console.log(marker_map());
    var locations = marker_map();
    var addresses = locations.address;
    var details_array = locations.details;
    // ======= Global variable to remind us what to do next
    var nextAddress = 0;

    // ======= Function to call the next Geocode operation when the reply comes back

    function theNext() {

        if (nextAddress < addresses.length) {
            setTimeout('getAddress("' + addresses[nextAddress] + '","' + nextAddress + '",theNext)', delay);
            nextAddress++;
        } else {
            // We're done. Show map bounds
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }

    // ======= Call that function for the first time =======
    theNext();

}
```

How do i solve?  I think this is to do with scope of functions because **getAddress** is clearly a function.

Comment: Function inside function is a local function.. Which can not be accessible from outside of the function....

Comment: Any idea on how to solve?

Comment: @user892134 I am not getting, what do you want exactly?

Comment: @Parag Bhayani , i explained it fully.  It is working code but when i put it in the function `view_maps`, which is triggered by a click it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you write `marker_map()` function outside the `view_maps()` function? and if you need `marker_map()` function inside  the `view_maps()` function then just make a call to `marker_map()` function inside it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your theNext function with this one.

```
function theNext() {
    if (nextAddress < addresses.length) {
    setTimeout(getAddress(addresses[nextAddress],nextAddress,theNext), delay);
    nextAddress++;
    } else {
        // We're done. Show map bounds
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}
```

see change in setTimeout, I am Calling function not passing string (which will evaluate later and search in global scope)

I also create a [demo](http://jsbin.com/hemiyalapu/edit?js,console,output) for proof of concept. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks but i tried this.  I get the error **Maximum call stack size exceeded** when this happens.  This code works fully but when i put it in a function i get these errors?

Comment: could you please create a demo using jsbin or something which you prefer. it will be easy for us to debug that